# Rails page does not appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to execute a ruby on rails project. I have done a few commands including `rails server`. The commands that I wrote are:

```
rails new first_proj;
    cd first_proj
    rails generate scaffold project name:string cost:decimal;
    bundle exec rake db:migrate
rails s
```

But I see no html page at `localhost:3000`. I see:

[image]

Can You help me?

Comment: I think you missed to start the server with `rails s`.

Comment: already done......

Comment: You should add that to your question than...

Comment: what do you see in the browser?

Comment: I add image ....thank you for your patience

Answer (score 2):

The page you're seeing is the default Rails root page (http://localhost:3000). So, your Rails install is working!

Now, type `http://localhost:3000/projects` into the address bar of your browser.

Hopefully, you will see the projects page generated by your scaffold command.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you are so inclined. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Install all dependencies

```
 bundle exec install
```

Then start the server

```
 bundle exec rails s
```

Then you should see something following:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using     127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-04-11 13:11:47] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-04-11 13:11:47] INFO  ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24) [i686-linux]
[2014-04-11 13:11:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6370 port=3000
```

if you open browser and type add address "http://localhost:3000" you shoud see the log of receiving a request

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-11 13:11:48 +0200
...
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
```

Comment: when you open  "http://localhost:3000"  do you see output:    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1    in  console?

Comment: after localhost I receive this log text:
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-20 23:33:45 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered /home/stefano/.gem/ruby/2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: I would like  seeing new.html.erb page instead

Comment: set root path in config/routes.rb:    root :to => 'someController#new'